# Scan list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to scan a list in Prolog.
In particular, I want to write a predicate scan_list (list), and I want to make it check to see if the current element is a positive integer and if so print it.

Thank's.

Comment: The question is hard to understand. Do you mean that you want to create the predicate `scan_list` that prints all positive integers from a list? If that's the case, what have you tried? What didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog there is `include/3`, e.g. you can write

```
?- include(<(0), [1, -2, 7, 9, 0, -1, 14, 0.8], L).
L = [1, 7, 9, 14, 0.8].
```

(Warning: this particular code accepts more numbers than positive integers.)

Answer (score 2):

If this is homework, be assured that the only way to learn any programming language is to practice it and think about the assignments. However, here is a version that might be, what you want

```
scan_list([]). 
scan_list([H|T]) :- H > 0,!, print(H),nl,scan_list(T). 
scan_list([_|T]) :- scan_list(T).
```

It works like that:

```
?- scan_list([1,-2,7,9,0,-1,14]).
1
7
9
14
yes
```

Comment: scan_list is not a good name for this predicate, because it does not tell you what the predicate does.

Comment: Well, I used the name the OP used. Regarding integers, you are clearly right.